# Problem with gateway server configuration on Centos 7

Tags: centos, networking, iptables, forwarding, gateway

I'm trying to configure a host with Centos 7 and one network interface (eth0) to be a gateway.

The problem is that Gateway can forward package, receive the answer but it fails with sending response to the Host:

`Host --> Gateway --> Destination --> Gateway -/-> Host`

Actually I can see in tcpdump that Gateway is sending response but Host is not receiving it.

tcpdump for `nc -v 192.168.253.113 22` request:

- Host:

  ```
  12:10:22.038563 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.0.47.21739 > 192.168.253.113.ssh: Flags [S], seq 3208534021, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 259369415 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
  12:10:23.040527 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.0.47.21739 > 192.168.253.113.ssh: Flags [S], seq 3208534021, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 259370418 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
  ```
- Gateway:

  ```
  12:10:22.038972 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.0.47.21739 > 192.168.253.113.ssh: Flags [S], seq 3208534021, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 259369415 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
  12:10:22.039017 22:22:22:22:22:22 > 33:33:33:33:33:33, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.0.19.21739 > 192.168.253.113.ssh: Flags [S], seq 3208534021, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 259369415 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
  12:10:22.140408 33:33:33:33:33:33 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.253.113.ssh > 10.0.0.19.21739: Flags [S.], seq 2142167154, ack 3208534022, win 28480, options [mss 1436,sackOK,TS val 2418584010 ecr 259369415,nop,wscale 10], length 0
  12:10:22.140427 22:22:22:22:22:22 > 11:11:11:11:11:11, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.253.113.ssh > 10.0.0.47.21739: Flags [S.], seq 2142167154, ack 3208534022, win 28480, options [mss 1436,sackOK,TS val 2418584010 ecr 259369415,nop,wscale 10], length 0
  12:10:23.040940 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.0.47.21739 > 192.168.253.113.ssh: Flags [S], seq 3208534021, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 259370418 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
  12:10:23.040958 22:22:22:22:22:22 > 33:33:33:33:33:33, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.0.19.21739 > 192.168.253.113.ssh: Flags [S], seq 3208534021, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 259370418 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
  12:10:23.141986 33:33:33:33:33:33 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.253.113.ssh > 10.0.0.19.21739: Flags [S.], seq 2142167154, ack 3208534022, win 28480, options [mss 1436,sackOK,TS val 2418584260 ecr 259369415,nop,wscale 10], length 0
  12:10:23.141998 22:22:22:22:22:22 > 11:11:11:11:11:11, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.253.113.ssh > 10.0.0.47.21739: Flags [S.], seq 2142167154, ack 3208534022, win 28480, options [mss 1436,sackOK,TS val 2418584260 ecr 259369415,nop,wscale 10], length 0
  ```

When I try the same request with Gateway as a destination (`nc -v 10.0.0.19 22`) all works fine:

- Host:

  ```
  12:16:46.222903 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.0.47.46354 > 10.0.0.19.ssh: Flags [S], seq 725877336, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 259753600 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
  12:16:46.224050 22:22:22:22:22:22 > 11:11:11:11:11:11, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.0.19.ssh > 10.0.0.47.46354: Flags [S.], seq 3167329297, ack 725877337, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 96976164 ecr 259753600,nop,wscale 9], length 0
  12:16:46.224104 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.47.46354 > 10.0.0.19.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 259753601 ecr 96976164], length 0
  12:16:46.232678 22:22:22:22:22:22 > 11:11:11:11:11:11, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 87: 10.0.0.19.ssh > 10.0.0.47.46354: Flags [P.], seq 1:22, ack 1, win 57, options [nop,nop,TS val 96976173 ecr 259753601], length 21
  12:16:46.232731 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.47.46354 > 10.0.0.19.ssh: Flags [.], ack 22, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 259753610 ecr 96976173], length 0
  12:16:49.692764 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.47.46354 > 10.0.0.19.ssh: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 22, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 259757070 ecr 96976173], length 0
  12:16:49.693905 22:22:22:22:22:22 > 11:11:11:11:11:11, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.19.ssh > 10.0.0.47.46354: Flags [F.], seq 22, ack 2, win 57, options [nop,nop,TS val 96979634 ecr 259757070], length 0
  12:16:49.693938 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.47.46354 > 10.0.0.19.ssh: Flags [.], ack 23, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 259757071 ecr 96979634], length 0
  ```
- Gateway:

  ```
  12:16:46.223731 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.0.47.46354 > 10.0.0.19.ssh: Flags [S], seq 725877336, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 259753600 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
  12:16:46.223793 22:22:22:22:22:22 > 11:11:11:11:11:11, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.0.19.ssh > 10.0.0.47.46354: Flags [S.], seq 3167329297, ack 725877337, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 96976164 ecr 259753600,nop,wscale 9], length 0
  12:16:46.224401 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.47.46354 > 10.0.0.19.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 259753601 ecr 96976164], length 0
  12:16:46.232728 22:22:22:22:22:22 > 11:11:11:11:11:11, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 87: 10.0.0.19.ssh > 10.0.0.47.46354: Flags [P.], seq 1:22, ack 1, win 57, options [nop,nop,TS val 96976173 ecr 259753601], length 21
  12:16:46.233033 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.47.46354 > 10.0.0.19.ssh: Flags [.], ack 22, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 259753610 ecr 96976173], length 0
  12:16:49.693106 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.47.46354 > 10.0.0.19.ssh: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 22, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 259757070 ecr 96976173], length 0
  12:16:49.693928 22:22:22:22:22:22 > 11:11:11:11:11:11, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.19.ssh > 10.0.0.47.46354: Flags [F.], seq 22, ack 2, win 57, options [nop,nop,TS val 96979634 ecr 259757070], length 0
  12:16:49.694218 11:11:11:11:11:11 > 22:22:22:22:22:22, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.47.46354 > 10.0.0.19.ssh: Flags [.], ack 23, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 259757071 ecr 96979634], length 0
  ```

I can also do the same thing from Gateway to the Host.

I have no idea what can be possibly wrong. It is my Gateway configuration:

Routes:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Iptables on Gateway (saved using `iptables-save`):

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [46:4191]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [38:11217]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [19:1044]
:INPUT ACCEPT [13:684]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10:1312]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

What I did is:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo FORWARD_IPV4=true >> /etc/sysconfig/network
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: A single-interface gateway is generally called "router on a stick," see if that doesn't help you find more info.

Comment: Did you remove the established traffic rule from iptables? Can you try adding this rule and restarting iptables: iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Comment: Could you post the output of `iptables -nL`. Your `tcpdump` output and your saved `iptables` rules don't seam to fit together. Also: Could you post the `tcpdump` command lines you used to produce the output above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you set any specific routes to the remote host.

To allow a host to reach remote host (presumely it is on a different network), it needs a route to get there. And the remote host itself needs to know how to get back to this host, which needs a route to return to the network the local host stays in.

If the remote host is in a network like 10.0.5.0/24 with remote gateway at 10.0.5.1. And your local gateway is: 10.0.3.1 and your local network is: 10.0.3.0/24. Adding a staic route on local host: 
`ip route add 10.0.5.0/24 via 10.0.3.1`

And add another static route on remote host:

`ip route add 10.0.3.0/24 via 10.0.5.1`

This is how I configure my network with similar situation like yours.